# Qt TabWidget Each tab Title Background Color

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets, qtabwidget

This is the original Tabwidget without setting title background color

[image]

My customer ask me to do something like this;
      Set different background colour for title

```
All - Yellow
purchase - light blue
POS Sales - light green
Cash Sales - Pink
invoice - light purple
```

I have try the SetStyleSheet like:

```
     QTabBar {
          background-color : Yellow;
     }
```

But all tab Color changed
   Somebody know how to setting each QTabBar background color?

Comment: Try to use different coloured icons on the tabs instead.

Comment: `ui->tableWidget->item(rowIndex,coloumIndex)->setBackgroundColor(QColor(color));` also `ui->tableWidget->item(rowIndex,coloumIndex)->setTextColor(QColor(color));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These properties can not be set through QSS. To change the style to each tab we must create a custom `QTabBar` and override its `paintEvent` method, to be able to change the style of each tab we use the `QStyleOptionTab` class, but to change the `QTabWidget` tabbar we need to use the `setTabBar` method but this is private so you need to create a custom `QTabWidget` as shown below:

**tabwidget.h**

```
#ifndef TABWIDGET_H
#define TABWIDGET_H

#include <QStyleOptionTab>
#include <QStylePainter>
#include <QTabWidget>

class TabBar: public QTabBar
{
public:
    TabBar(const QHash<QString, QColor> &colors, QWidget *parent=0):QTabBar(parent){
        mColors = colors;
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent */*event*/){

        QStylePainter painter(this);
        QStyleOptionTab opt;

        for(int i = 0;i < count();i++)
        {
            initStyleOption(&opt,i);
            if(mColors.contains(opt.text)){
                opt.palette.setColor(QPalette::Button, mColors[opt.text]);
            }

            painter.drawControl(QStyle::CE_TabBarTabShape, opt);
            painter.drawControl(QStyle::CE_TabBarTabLabel,opt);
        }
    }


private:
    QHash<QString, QColor> mColors;
};

class TabWidget : public QTabWidget
{
public:
    TabWidget(QWidget *parent=0):QTabWidget(parent){

        // text - color
        QHash <QString, QColor> dict;

        dict["All"] = QColor("yellow");
        dict["purchase"] = QColor("#87ceeb");
        dict["POS Sales"] = QColor("#90EE90");
        dict["Cash Sales"] = QColor("pink");
        dict["invoice"] = QColor("#800080");

        setTabBar(new TabBar(dict));
    }
};

#endif // TABWIDGET_H
```

And to use it in our QTabWidget in Qt Designer should be promoted for this we right click on the tabwidget and select the menu Promoted Widgets, in my case the previous code is created in the file tabwidget.h so this will be the header file and in the case of Promoted Class Name we use TabWidget, after that we press the buttons Add and Promote obtaining what is shown in the following image:

[image]

The final result is shown in the following image:

[image]

<sub>The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/46137500)</sub>

---

Python:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, colors, parent=None):
        super(TabBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mColors = colors

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()

        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            if opt.text in self.mColors:
                opt.palette.setColor(
                    QtGui.QPalette.Button, self.mColors[opt.text]
                )
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        d = {
            "All": QtGui.QColor("yellow"),
            "purchase": QtGui.QColor("#87ceeb"),
            "POS Sales": QtGui.QColor("#90EE90"),
            "Cash Sales": QtGui.QColor("pink"),
            "invoice": QtGui.QColor("#800080"),
        }
        self.setTabBar(TabBar(d))

        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "All")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "purchase")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "POS Sales")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "Cash Sales")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "invoice")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    w = TabWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Seen, It no effect in window's system... Am I forgot Install something to Qt? i use version 5.9.1

Comment: Yes, I have download your example file for trying & try to promote to my project tabwidget. Following step by step but don't have effect.

Comment: this is the project download from your's [link](https://github.com/SmithSong55/QTabwigetProject/tree/master/46137500-qt-tabwidget-each-tab-title-background-color)

Comment: This is the another project I Create for testing, still no effect [link](https://github.com/SmithSong55/QTabwigetProject/tree/master/TestingTabwidget) [image](https://github.com/SmithSong55/QTabwigetProject/blob/master/TestingTabwidget/Screenshot.png)

Comment: I Send My Teamviewer Id and Pass here?

Comment: so the solution is add a.setStyle("fusion");  to main.cpp. thanks @eyllanesc

Comment: Seen I still have lot to learn,Thank ya. I continue my works.

Comment: If you are on Qt4 (like me), you will have more success setting the color on the QPalette::Window instead of QPalette::Button